# element (button) was gotten ajax response not work?

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have a site to update Status and Comment
I have  to list all my status and comment query from database
and I have form to update when update it insert before  I use html code like a status a comment button don't work
My code is
First is return String for ajax request

```
            echo '
    <div class="stbody">
        <div class="stimg">
            <img width="40" height="40" src="/images/uploads/.' . $json_data["picture"] .'">
       </div>
        <div class="sttext">' .
         "  AAAAAAA" .
        '</div>
        <a href="#" class="delete" style="display: none; "> Remove</a>

        <a href="#"id ="comment_link">Comment</a>
        <span class="icodot"> 5 comment</span>
        <span class="likelink"><a  href="" isliked="0">Like</a> 10 liked</span>
        <div id="box_comment" class="bxcomment">
            <form>
                <div id="status' . $model->status_id . '" class="rowcomment" >
                    <div class="rowcommentlt">
                        <a>
                            <img width="40" height="40" src="http://3.1.s50.avatar.zdn.vn/avatar_files/3/c/d/8/giaosudau_50_3.jpg">
                        </a>                                        
                        <textarea class ="text_area"  id="txtComment' . $model->status_id . '"></textarea>
                        <br>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="bxcmtend">
                        <span class="tipcmtend">Nhấn Shift + Enter để xuống dòng</span>
                        <span class="btncmtend">
                            <a class="comment_submit" href="#" 
                            onclick="return false;" id="' . $model->status_id . '"><em>Comment</em></a>             
                            <a onclick="return false;" rel="for_3073657831" id="emofeed_3073657831" class="emofeed" href="#" tabindex="0"></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div> 

';
```

In recevie I have script to handle update status and update comment
**first is handle comment**

```
$(".comment_submit").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var status_id = element.attr("id");
    var comment = $("#txtComment"+status_id).val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&status_id=' + status_id;
    if(comment=='')
    {
        alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else
    {

        $("#flash"+status_id).show();
        $("#flash"+status_id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> loading.....');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#loadplace"+Id).append(html);
                $("#flash"+Id).hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

**second is handle update status**

```
success: function(data){

                $(data).prependTo(".timeline").slideDown("slow");                                
                $(".loading").hide();
                $(".input_box").val("So what's on your mind?").css("color","#808080")
                .css("height","30px");
            }
```

When I receive html code is OK but I click in Comment It doesn't work.

Thank for advance.
**What should I do I should response to client json and in client I insert them with html code?**

Comment: In the comment_submit (html a element) you have an inline event handler "onclick". This takes priority over the jquery bound "click". Remove the inline onclick handler to tidy things up and it helps remove unknown problems.

Comment: May I see the controller handling this?

Answer (score 1):

I have asked a guy I got my problem is handle event in all page you should use .on() or live()
in this case I change from `$(".comment_submit").click(function(){` to `$(document).on('click', '.comment_submit', function(){`

and It works.
Thank for all you guys

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the reponse never works? IN

```
$("#loadplace"+Id).append(html); 
$("#flash"+Id).hide();
```

the "ID" is undefined. This means the response will never show. You probably mean status_id?

Comment: but I not work when I not enter any character to text area alert("Please Enter Some Text"); Id in here is not my problem. Thank for your answer